# NaN message, even when all the Javascript working seems fine in Recursive function

Tags: javascript, html, nan

I have written some javascript code in which i have made a recursive function. I am expecting a numeric value however i recieve an NaN. How can i solve this?

```
<script language="javascript">
    function toperform()
    {
        var proceed=confirm("Do you want to proceed?");
        if (proceed==true)
        {
            var a = checknum("num1");
            var b = checknum("num2");
            alert("The sum is "+(a+b));                                             
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You chose not to proceed!");
        }
    }
    function checknum(arg)
    {
        var num=parseInt(prompt("Enter "+arg));                                     
        if (isNaN(num))
        {
            alert("Please enter a valid number");
            num=checknum(arg);
        }
        return num;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: did you received an alert from checknum? i would put a debugger; line after that to watch the arguments

Comment: i did. i get the pop-up and recieve all the messages.

Comment: Works fine here on Chromium browser.  http://jsfiddle.net/mGWYv/

Comment: Which number(s) were you trying when you got the NaN message?

Comment: Same on firefox on @Paul jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more semantic, repeat until get a valid number, but not recursively

```
function checknum(arg)
    {
        var num = null ; 
        while (isNaN(num))
        {
            if (num != null)
                alert("Please enter a valid number");   
            var input = prompt("Enter "+arg);
            num = parseInt(input);              
        }
        return num;
    }
```

Comment: this is great, but what if i wanted to do it recursively. i mean i have done it, what i dont get is why im getting an NaN. It doesnt make sense.

Comment: Seems that in the jsfiddle it's working. On what browser are you triying?